# Throwing business exceptions

Tags: c#, design-patterns, exception

To invoke external services such as payment gateways I create a provider assembly such as: MyCompany.Providers.Braintree, which encapsulates all the logic related to making the service invocation. It works basically as pass through and it is contained in is own assembly.

Let's say the provider has a "DoPayment" method which invokes a service on the gateway which returns a couple of status as well as a body message:

- code 111 -> Payment was successfully
- code 222 -> Not enough funds
- code 333 -> Unknown payee

Should the provider throw a "business" exception when the payment has not completed successfully, or should the service basically return a type which wraps what the gateway returned?

I have always opted out for not throwing exceptions in these kind of situations because basically this is not ab exception case - the gateway processed the request successfully (the request was processed even thought the payment was not completed) this process is Microsoft's recommendation as well:

[Creating and Throwing Exceptions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx)

> Exceptions should not be used to change the flow of a program as part of ordinary execution. Exceptions should only be used to report and handle error conditions.

Martin Fowler also has opinions on the matter, [Replacing Throwing Exceptions with Notification in Validations](http://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html)

> Exceptions signal something outside the expected bounds of behavior of the code in question

But it's related to input validation.

What do you guys do?

Comment: You answered the question by yourself. This is a  define business logic and the result is a define System status, because of that, no reason for a Exception.

Comment: But is there some pattern that defines the usage of Exceptions in a general context?

Comment: Yes Microsoft has guidelines https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ey5ey87(v=vs.71).aspx. The relevant part for you is: "Do not use exceptions for normal or expected errors, or for normal flow of control."

Comment: Yes I know that, but exceptions are specific to MS stack, surely there must be a few broader general rules